# Grepping for a sentence from inside a bash script

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, grep

I have a log file from which I want to grep for some error messages using a bash script, however I am not quite getting how to pass it the sentence and then use it in the grep call.

```
$./grep_sentence_script.sh "Call to server failed"

grep_sentence.sh

#!/bin/sh
sentence=$1
`grep $sentence logfile.log`
```

Could someone please help me with it.

Answer (score 2):

Just this will be sufficient:

```
#!/bin/bash

grep -iF "$1" logfile.log
```

Important to use `-F` (fixed string) option in order to avoid regex interpretation of special meta characters like `$`, `.` etc.

Comment: `$@` in `grep -iF "$@" logfile.log` is sort of misleading. `"$1"` is better?

Answer (score 2):

put the variable inside double quotes.

```
#!/bin/sh
sentence=$1
grep "$sentence" logfile.log
```